# How to get rid of installed .exe files?

Tags: uninstall

How do I get rid of any .exe files installed through Wine for example?
Is there some general rule or way where are .exe software stored and I can just click and get rid off them?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu? "where are .exe software stored" where you put them ... " I can just click and get rid off them?" .exe are not a valid Linux executable so I would not click them and just delete them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you meant 'Wine' software, used in Linux for executing Windows software on Linux.

In that case, just go to the Wine option through menu, use '**Uninstall Wine Software**' option, (on a slow computer, it may take a while) a window will appear with title of '**Add/Remove Programs**'.

This window's Applications tab shows the currently Wine installed Windows software onto your Linux. Select the Windows program you want to un-install, then click the '*Remove*' button.

Answer (score 1):

If the program is not listed in the Add '**Add/Remove Programs**', use the Ubuntu Dash and search for "**Browse C: Drive**". Click on the *first* result that appears (*make sure it's and application*). This will open WINE's C: drive in the file manager. Now you can just go into the "Program Files" folder and delete to your hearts content!